# How to monitor RAID1 system with Dell PERC H200 controller?

Tags: linux, monitoring, hardware-raid, dell-perc, fedora-20

I have a server configured with RAID1 using a Dell PERC H200 controller. I tried to use smartmontools to monitor the disks. But after installing it and running the command, it says SMART support is unavailable:

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda
...
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Dell
Product:              Virtual Disk
Revision:             1028
Device type:          disk
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
```

There are no entries of `megaraid` or `megadev` in `/proc/device`. I am using Fedora 20.  How does one normally monitor the discs behind such a RAID card in Fedora?

Comment: maybe you can use MegaCli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost wanted to install Dell's OMSA tool. But it says on the [Wiki page](http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/omsa.html)

> Fedora: The community releases are officially unsupported in this
>   repository. You can, however, fake it by editing the yum config and
>   changing "fc" to "el5". This is completely unsupported. If it breaks
>   you can keep all the pieces.

Luckily after further Googling, I found this [article](http://karol.miaskiewicz.com/?p=627) and realize that it is only a matter of choosing the correct device.

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sg1
...
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST3300657SS
Revision:             ES66
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
```

Comment: As you already found it yourself, instead of using `smartctl -a /dev/sda` which tries to access the virtual disk of your two drivew in RAID 1, simply use `smartctl -a /dev/sg1` and `smartctl -a /dev/sg2` to access the two disks. No need to install anything else than smartmontools.

Answer (score 2):

Usually installing the [megaraid tools from lsi](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/MegaRAID%20Common%20Files/14.02.01.03_Linux_x64_MSM.tar.gz) would work. Make sure to read the readme to install 32 bit libraries, and to start the vivaldi service. I don't think they are certified for fedora, though - the rpms are for rhel5/6. Not sure if source rpm exists, or if generic linux is supported.

Comment: I 2nd this - I work in Dell support and I've had some success with MegaCLI on unsupported distros, though I've not tried on Fedora before.